# Nested C Array Struct Alignment in Clang

Tags: c++, templates, memory, clang, padding

I have a small memory problem in C++17 using Clang compiling for x64. Since I work with low level memory copies to specialized hardware, I do depend on the memory being aligned as expected. I have recently moved from Visual Studio to Clang and have encountered the following issue:

See the below code:

```
struct ContainerRoot{};
template<size_t t_size, class t_type>
struct Container : public ContainerRoot
{
    t_type contents[t_size];
};

static_assert(sizeof(Container<1, double>) == 8);           //This works as expected
static_assert(sizeof(Container<4, double>) == 32);          //This works as expected
static_assert(sizeof(Container<16, double>) == 128);        //This works as expected
static_assert(sizeof(Container<4, Container<4, double>>) == 128); //This fails.
```

In the above example sizeof(Container< Container>) is actually 136 (an extra 8 bytes). My question is why is an extra 8 bytes getting added in, and can I avoid it? I would love to use the Clang compiler, but if there isn't a workaround for this, it may not be worth rewriting all of the code surrounding sending this data to the specialized hardware.

Thus far, I have checked using std::is_polymorphic< Container <4, Container<4, double>>>() just to confirm there wasn't some virtual lookup table being added to the class.

Comment: `Container<Container<double>>` shouldn't compile: `Container` requires two template arguments.

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/QBcQNj)

Comment: Sorry trying to make a simplistic example. Didn't actually test compiling. Cleaned up the example a bit.

Comment: Given that `Container` actually inherits from something: Is RTTI activated? If so the compiler probably adds an empty vftable anyways just to know which type its dealing with. Also explains different behaviours with different compilers. Oddly: I would expect more overhead though in that case.

Comment: Interessting: Fails even if RTTI is deactivated. But notice: `sizeof(Container<4,double>[4]) == 128`. Also works if the inheritance is removed. Seems like a problem with empty base class optimization (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo):

> The size of any object or member subobject
>   [...] is required to be at
>   least 1 even if the type is an empty class type (that is, a class or
>   struct that has no non-static data members), in order to be able to
>   guarantee that the addresses of distinct objects of the same type are
>   always distinct.

This constraint doesn't apply to empty bases (Empty Base Optimization).

However, en.cppreference.com also notes:

> Empty base optimization is prohibited if one of the empty base classes
>   is also the type or the base of the type of the first non-static data
>   member, since the two base subobjects of the same type are required to
>   have different addresses within the object representation of the most
>   derived type.

Which is unfortunately the case when dealing with `Container<4, Container<4, double>>` as both the first member, which has type `Container<4, double>`, as well as `Container<4, Container<4, double>>` both inherit from `ContainerRoot`.

As such I would hypothesize that MSVC is actually wrong in this case and prematurely applies an optimization which it must not do.

Comment: @cigien Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Not sure I understand the reasoning behind the: "since the two base subobjects of the same type are required to have different addresses within the object representation of the most derived type.". The reason for the base class in this case serves no purpose other than to provide certain helper functions. For example: 'template<class t_type>
 typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ContainerRoot, t_type>::value, t_type>::type abs(const t_type& value){...};'

Comment: @TylerParke I don't completely see the point either but the problem seems to be that both `(ContainerBase*)(container)` and `(ContainerBase*)(container.contents[0])` share the same address **AND** the same type. I believe that poses a problem when a method of `ContainerBase` is called by `content`, e.g `contents[0].baseMethod();`. When the method gets called its not clear on which object it operates on and how it should differentiate. Should it operate on the enclosing `Container` object or should it act on `contents[0]`? Both have the same address and both call the same func.

Comment: Ahhh now I'm very curious as to what happens in VS using your above pointer example. That actually makes complete sense.